# Select listview item on second click

Tags: android, listview

The code populates the listview with items using baseadapter. On clicking on the item it changes background color and goes to the next activity. Now i want to change the back ground color on first click and it should stay selected. Then on next click it should go to the next activity. Is it possible to do so.

Activity

```
    nameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_names);
    nameList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

    nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
 {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long viewId) 
{

    TextView PCNtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.value_Name);
    String P_Name = PCNtv.getText().toString();

    Intent intents = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
    intents.putExtra("P_Name", P_Name);

    view.setSelected(true);                    
    startActivity(intents);
      }
    });
```

In drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue_color"/> 
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/white_color"/> 
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_color"/> 
</selector>
```

Comment: Take a counter as int variable, increase it after clicking. If counter is 2 the start activity.

Comment: Do you want to select multiple items or just one (aka selecting new one leads to unselecting previous)?

Comment: @skywall just one item i want to select.

Comment: @Bansal i will try to do it.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with a counter.  Each time the item is clicked check the isSelected() and if it is already selected, go to the next activity.

Comment: @GaryBak can you show me how to do that please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the views selected property to detect the second click.  First click will select the view, the second will open the activity.

```
nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long viewId) 
  {

      TextView PCNtv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.value_Name);
      String P_Name = PCNtv.getText().toString();

      if ( view.isSelected() ) {
           Intent intents = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
           intents.putExtra("P_Name", P_Name);
           startActivity(intents);
      }
      view.setSelected(true);                    
    });
 }
```

**Update**

The selection is lost when the users presses the view again, so the code above does not work.  Here is a solution involving the adapter tracking the currently selected position.

The click event:

```
 nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // Check to see which item in the adapter is already
        // selected, if the same has been selected twice, start new activity
        if ( i == ((TestAdapter)adapter).getSelectedIndex()) {

           // Start your new activity here.
           Log.d("TAG", "second push");
        }

        ((TestAdapter)adapter).setSelectedIndex(i);
     }
  });
```

You did not show the code for your adapter, so here is a simple one with the selected index added:

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {

      private final Activity context;
      private int mSelection = -1;

      public TestAdapter(Activity context, String[] objects) {
         super(context, R.layout.text_layout, objects);
         this.context = context;
      }

      // Call this when an item is clicked, this sets the 
      // internal index for the selected item and notifies the view
      // that the data has changes, this will force the view to draw
      // allowing it to correctly highlight the selected item

      public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
         mSelection = index;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      // This is needed for the click listener to check to see which
      // item is already selected
      public int getSelectedIndex() {
         return mSelection;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
         View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, null);

         TextView tv = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
         tv.setText(getItem(position));

         // Adds or removes the selection on the view so
         // it will display as selected
         if ( mSelection == position ) {
            tv.setSelected(true);
         } else {
            tv.setSelected(false);
         }

         return rowView;
      }

   }
```

**Updated: added inline comments**

Comment: What is the behavior if the user selects row 2 once and then row 3?  Does row 2 loose its selection or do they both become selected?

Comment: When i click first the item changes color. and then when i click second time it stays on same activity. And for you question - yes it looses its selection.

Comment: It is not entering the if condition after view.setSelected(true);

Comment: Yes, the view looses selection when it is touched again.  I'll update my answer with a more complex solution, which also solves the multi-selection problem.

Comment: I should add the intent portion into if condition

Comment: Great. Its working now. Could you explain a bit more please, so that i will understand.

Comment: Added some comments in-line.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort.